# A Great Adventure! - Part 1

Tags: cipher, visual

You work at the local library and it can be ever so tedious.
So you decide to search through the archives for anything that might be of interest.
When searching through a box you find a sealed letter which isn't catalogued.
You're about to return it to your manager until you turn it over to see a red wax seal with what looks like an eagle printed into it. On the back it reads: ***"For the bold!"***.
You decide to open it an inside you find a coupon!

[image]

The letter reads:

> Hello to you fortunate enough to find this letter,
>   Though I may be long gone my legacy may continue, therefore I will great you my life’s greatest treasure!
>   However you must first prove worthy of using such an item and for that I grant you this voucher.
>   It will show you to your destination and so you may find what you seek.
>   My identity will remain muddled for now but you may find me later in your adventure.
>   Measure your options carefully and good luck!
>   **G.G.Crease**

What should you do next?

---

Hint 1:

> This is the original barcode (not resized or compressed):
>  [image]
>  The barcode number is: 114199211541116212432111

Hint 2:

> Great this adventure would be,
>  Provided I knew where to begin,
>  So where is the clue I should see,
>  Can I ever get rid of my sin?

Hint 3:

> Some claim it to be better,
>  Then any man-made before,
>  With only one of two options,
>  The language that paints the door.

---

> *I will post the next part when this is solved or if it remains unanswered for over a month!*

Comment: My identity will remain muddled - anagrams of GG CREASE don't give anything unless you count 'race eggs' as a solution.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I'm gonna have to say that you may be on to something but its not important right now ;)

Comment: oh wow! :P I'm half getting some of these clues. Measure your options seems to indicate distances between the lines are important - scanning it certainly doesn't give anything.... Nothing solid yet though

Comment: @BMS21.. does the process of solving this puzzle requires scanning of the provided barcode through a barcode scanner / mobile device / other means ?... If so ...it is going to .... the readers very much !

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay The barcode has to be used but you shouldn't have to scan it!

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay already tried to scan it - it isn't a valid barcode

Comment: well it SEEMs to me that the pixel widths of the blocks from left to right are 4 2 15 3 33 32 7 3 5 17 15 2 5 3 22 6 5 6 15 10 8 3 4 3 3, but there's some anti-aliasing going on so it might not be accurate.

Comment: @BMS21 I saw your edit. Would you consider adding a hint before you release the next step? I wouldn't want to have the answer spoiled

Comment: @DavidFoong Of course I will probably give at least 2 im just thinking in a months time or something XD

Answer (score 1):

Based on what is presented so far I would head for Sea World in Orlando Florida because that picture is the same picture they put on their tickets to the Orca pool.  That should answer the question asked in the puzzle:  "What should you do next?"

What I would do after that is to use the bar code as a device to measure in the image to find the location of something.  A cursory glance seems to reveal that the meduim width black bar is close to the same width as the black stripe in the awning behind the Orca in the picture.  I would go and look around there for more clues.

That's what I would do next and then some.

Edit:
Upon further investigation it appears that some character named Cregg was arrested back in 2004 for stealing and selling Sea World tickets...

Comment: Nice thought I stole the image for effect but thats not correct sorry!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was, this barcode is exactly 24 signs and the first letters of the second hint spell GPSC which i interpreted as meaning for GPS Corrdinates.

> 11.4199211541;11.6212432111

So i put [this into Google Maps](https://www.google.at/maps/@11.4199211541,11.6212432111,10z) and...

...unfortunately ended up at some Nigerian Scammer... :(

Comment: Your thinking along the correct lines but not quite there yet ;)